# Phone Pads program

Tags: java

вот мой код:

```
    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    String letter = input.nextLine();
    char ch = letter.charAt(0);
    ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

    int num = 0;
    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
        if(ch >= 'W' || ch >= 'w')
            num = 9;
        else if (ch >= 'T' || ch >= 't')
            num = 8;
        else if (ch >= 'P' || ch >= 'p')
            num = 7;
        else if (ch >= 'M' || ch >= 'm')
            num = 6;
        else if (ch >= 'J' || ch >= 'j')
            num = 5;
        else if (ch >= 'G' || ch >= 'g')
            num = 4;
        else if (ch >= 'D'||ch >= 'd')
            num = 3;
        else if (ch >= 'A' || ch >= 'a')
            num = 2;
        System.out.println("The corresponding number is "+num);
    }
    else
        System.out.println(ch+" is invalid input");
```

скажите пожалуйста зачем нужен этот метод в этом коде:

```
ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
```

если вы введёте с маленькой буквой или с большой буквой должен быть тот же ответ, т.е я могу вводить с заглавной буквой и с маленькой. Ну раз дан метод 
.toUpperCase(ch) все буквы же будут заглавными??? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код переводит маленькие буквы в большие

```
ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
```

если вы введёте с маленькой буквой или с большой то значение результата будет с большой буквой. Поэтому проверку маленьких букв можно убрать

```
if(ch == 'W')
            num = 9;
        else if (ch == 'T')
            num = 8;
        else if (ch == 'P')
            num = 7;
        else if (ch == 'M')
            num = 6;
        else if (ch == 'J')
            num = 5;
        else if (ch == 'G')
            num = 4;
        else if (ch == 'D')
            num = 3;
        else if (ch == 'A')
            num = 2;
```

Comment: но почему можно убрать проверку маленьких букв?

Comment: Потому, что получаются только большие буквы